# How can i achieve to one value in XAML and use it

Tags: xaml

Here's my problem:

```
<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="330" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="445" Margin="100,114,0,0">
            <Line X1="10" Y1="10" X2="420" Y2="10" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" />
```

I would like to set X1 value to MyCanvas.Height one. How can i do this? :O

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
<Line X1="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=MyCanvas}" Y1="10" X2="420" Y2="10" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" />
```